# Save UIDatePicker Value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uidatepicker

I have a date picker, I want to save the value user gave, so next time user goes back to that view controller, the date picker is still set to the value given last time.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
class Setting: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time




        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

}

Comment: Ok, what have you tried? What research have you done? Where do you think you should read the value from the date picker? Where do you think you should put the saved date value back into the date picker? Do you want it to save the user choice even if the user quits the app and re-launches it, or just if they close the VC and then come back? Think through this and see if you can work it out. If you get back, post SPECIFIC questions, but we're not going to do it all for you.

Comment: Are you intending on persisting any other data in your app? If so, are you investigating the use of Core Data? For your information the property `datePicker.date` will hold the information you are wanting to save.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Cast it to a variable then load that variable into the data field!

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html